# In python how to mix two sentence?

Tags: python

I am new to python
   and I want to make the first character from the first string, followed by the last character from the second string
      like this

```
    >>>String("aceg", "kjihfdb")
     abcdefghijk
```

Comment: It seems like you'd just want to reverse the second string, then interleave the two. That's two distinct operations, and searching should result yield results for both.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, I voted to close for... needing more detail, maybe? Anyway, I didn't vote for that duplicate. I'm not crazy about how SO shows that now as it often misrepresents close votes.

Comment: @Carcigenicate: I voted to reopen.

Comment: @Chris Oh, that's weird. I thought you hammered it (although now that I'm checking, I see that it doesn't show a gold next to your name. Sorry).

Comment: This question is not a duplicate of what's linked. This doesn't border on simple string concatenation. Needs to be **unclosed**.

Comment: @Carcigenicate, there appear to be _two_ Chris users who voted to close. I don't have a gold [tag:python] badge. The other Chris does.

Comment: I feel that this should be closed for other reasons: it needs a clear problem statement, rather than "I don't know how to do this."

Comment: ... and sure enough, my "reopen" vote failed because others beat me to it.  Now ...

Comment: This is a beginner we're chasing away. Just keep that in mind.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and ... [the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  StackOverflow is a knowledge base for *specific* programming problems -- not a coding or tutorial resource.  This exercise is to make you learn some string manipulation.  You've already identified that you need to reverse the second string and interleave with the first.  Show us your attempt to code this.

Comment: @Robert, please have a look at this gist I created just for you https://gist.github.com/mfonism/f450f0ca192aac8e4811a202b1690d43 &mdash; where I explain the logic you need to create you code.

Comment: If you get stuck, we'll help the specific needs, but walking you through the logic to a solution is about three steps outside the Stack Overflow charter.  Meet us part-way, and we should be able to get you through the rest.

Comment: @Prune, the OP hasn't identified that they need to reverse the second string and interleave with the first. Someone else did that. In my experience, most people who ask questions like this have no clue how to start. But a gentle nudge in the right direction will get them firing on all cylinders. We shouldn't be too ready to close n00b1e questions. So, we don't want to spoon-feed them with the code &mdash; that's okay... but let's hold their hands and teach them how to think!

Comment: All your answer is in [Python tutorial: 3.1.2 Strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings), please read it, then try some code. `s[0]` gets you the 0'th character from `s`, for example.

Answer (score 4):

First, let me make it clear that it's always best practice to provide a rundown of what attempts you have made to tackle the problem. This way, it makes it easier for other people to point out where you might have gone wrong and lead you to the right direction.

This point notwithstanding, here's one way to approach the problem using basic recursion.

```py
def String(str1, str2):
    if len(str1) == 0:
        return str2[::-1]
    elif len(str2) == 0:
        return str1
    else:
        return str1[0] + str2[-1] + String(str1[1:], str2[:-1])
```

As with any recursion problem, we establish a base case. In the context of this question, the base case would be if any of the arguments of the `String` function are empty. If the first argument is empty, we have to reverse the second string; conversely, if the second string is of length 0, we simply return the first string as it is. If neither of them are empty, we invoke a recursive call on the function, as shown in the last `else` statement. Specifically, we concatenate the first character of the first string and the last character of the last string with the returned result of the recursive call.

If anything is unclear, I'd be happy to answer any additional questions you might have.

Comment: The problem is clearly asking this and this is a good solution.

Comment: Excellent solution!

Answer (score 0):

```py
def weave_words(first, second):
    ...
```

Let's do this by hand.

```py
first = "aceg"
second = "kjihfdb"
```

First, you want to reverse the second word (and keep the first word as is):

```py
first = "aceg"
second = "bdfhijk"
```

Then, you want to *weave* them together, picking one element from each word in turn, until one of them (the shorter word) runs out of elements, then you just tack the remaining elements in the other (the longer word) onto the result.

You can start by trimming the longer one so that it is equal in length to the shorter one.

```py
first  = "aceg"
second = "bdfh"
remainder = "ijk"
```

Then you weave the equal length arms like so:

```py
weave = "abcdefgh"
remainder = "ijk"
```

Then tack the remainder onto it:

```py
weave = "abcdefgh"
```

Try to work with this logic to get a solution for yourself. If you don't eventually reach a satisfactory solution, feel free to reach out in the comment section under this answer. I'll provide you with code and explanation.

But first, you'll have to show me your own attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Funny oneline solution :

```py
def String(a, b):
    return ''.join(''.join((a[index], b[-index - 1])) for index in range(min(len(a), len(b)))) + (b[-len(a) - 1::-1] if len(a) < len(b) else a[len(b) or 1 - 1:])


print(String(a, b))
```

Answer (score 0):

With some `itertools`...

```
>>> ''.join(chain(*zip_longest(s, reversed(t), fillvalue='')))
'abcdefghijk'
```